# Which method is called while a UITableViewCell is selected or highlighted

Tags: ios, uitableview

While a tableviewcell selected or highlighted, we find it's background color is changed(for example, change to blue). I want to know how many methods are called during the process and what method. Wish to your answer!

Moreover, I want to know some methods deeply, such as, which method is called and changed the background color.

Comment: I down vote this because you have not shown that what you have tried and what problem you face it that. you have not done this because you have not try anything otherwise you find all method here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This forum is not to learn basic. First read some tutorial on same topic. Try something to create and if you face problem in that than ask here.

Answer (score 1):

These methods gets called and If you want to override it with your needs then you must override  these methods .

```
- (void)setHighlighted: (BOOL)highlighted animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    // don't highlight
}

- (void)setSelected: (BOOL)selected animated: (BOOL)animated 
{
    // don't select
    //[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

[Here is the Documentary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html)

Comment: I want to know some methods deeply, such as, which method is called and change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

These are the methods called on `UITableViewCell` taped event:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  // do something
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  // do something
}
```

Visit Apple Documentation for set/select on `UITableViewCell`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW69

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW3

In addition you can have more controls from:

```
 - (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
     { 
         // do something 
     }
 - (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
     { 
        // do something
     }
```

Comment: I want to know some methods deeply, such as, which method is called and change the background color.

Comment: First two methods are called when you tap on a tableView. These methods are already implemented in native classes of `UITableViewCell` and perform background color change and degault native customizations. When we need do some custom effects on then these methods are overridden in you custom class, so that you can do you own customizations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe I have not said clearly.My question is ,I add a customeview on the tableviewcell, and find customeview's drawRect: method is called while seleting the cell, I want to know what method of UITableviewCell class is called and make the customeview's drawRect:method to call.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Table View class, I've found this order:

```
tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

You can learn more if you open the UITableView header file.

Comment: I want to know some methods deeply, such as, which method is called and changed the background color.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? You mean which one changes to blue?

Comment: Yeah, I want to know it.

Comment: The didHighlight method turns the cell blue. You can test it by creating a tableView, then adding NSLogs (least that's how I test / debug my programs) or breakpoints.

Comment: I add a customeview on the tableviewcell, and find customeview's drawRect: method is called while seleting the cell, I want to know what method of UITableviewCell class is called and make the customeview's drawRect:method to call.